# Remapping a fan to work with a different temperature sensor?

Tags: drivers, fan, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

I have what seems to be a driver problem on my machine powered by Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. A fan is sporadically driven to full speed and I noticed that when that happens the `sensors` command reports `temp1` under `thinkpad-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter` as `N/A`.

```
$ sensors
...
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        6932 RPM
temp1:            N/A    
...
acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
...
```

Would it be possible to remap this fan to another temperature sensor, so that it changes its speed according to the reading of another temperature sensor, for example that of `temp1` under `acpitz-acpi-0 Adapter: ACPI interface`, which, I checked, always reports the same temperature as the unreliable `temp1` above?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I updated the question. It's Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.